# Recursive feature elimination with fix start set

Tags: python, feature-selection, rfe

Is there any way to give RFECV (recursive feature elimination cross validation) a fixed feature set so that the result contains all defined fixed feature sets?
For example, that you can give the function a list of names that contains the features that have to be kept.

I can't find something like this in the documentation (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.RFECV.html).

Or are there similar libraries like RFECV that have this option?